# React .setState returns type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React v 16.3.2 and am building an app to communicate orders with a DB on Firebase, also using axios 0.18.0.

I'm expecting that once I hit a certain button (continue) it will create this spinner effect on the screen as it loads, so I have the following code:

```
purchaseContinueHandler = () => {
        this.setState = ({loading: true});
        const order = {
            ingredients: this.state.ingredients,
            price: this.state.totalPrice,
            customer: {
                name: 'Name',
                address: {
                    street: 'teststreet 1',
                    zipCode: '86753',
                    country: 'U.S.'
                },
                email: 'example@example.com'
            },
            deliveryMethod: 'fastest'
        }
        axios.post('/orders.json', order)
            .then(response => { this.setState( { loading: false } );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState( { loading: false } ); //**<--This is where i get the error**
            });
    }
```

I run it and hit Continue on the app and get the error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this.setState is not a function

and it points to the line listed above.

Ran into [this documentation](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/issues/283) and tried to implement the solution that worked for him (create a `constructor()` and bind `this` to `this`) but that didn't work.

I was reading that this was no longer automatically added to the function but not sure what to do with that information, I'm pretty new to React still.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are **assigning** an object to `setState` in the first line of code, so when you try to call it later it no longer is a function...

```
this.setState = ({loading: true});
```

should be

```
this.setState({loading: true})
```

Comment: Also, you can use `Promise.finally` to avoid writing both `then` and `catch`:

    `axios.post("/orders.json", order).finally(() => {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    });`

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` is a function, you change it to an `JavaScript` `Object`, I guess it's a tiny mistake, you have to write:

```
this.setState({loading: true})
```

Use it not change it to other things.